# Getting DbEntityValidationException when I'm trying to update a row in a table using entity framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to update a row in my table `bu.LastReviewCreationDate = LastReviewCreationDate;`, but this action generate a DbEntityValidationException.

```js
      public void UpdateLastReviewCreationDate(string idBusiness, DateTime LastReviewCreationDate,string urlSite) {

            DAL.Business bu;
            try {
                using (DBContext tpContext = new DBContext())
                {
                    bu = tpContext.business.Find(idBusiness, urlSite);
                    if (bu != null)
                    {
                        bu.LastReviewCreationDate = LastReviewCreationDate;
                        tpContext.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
```

So This is what I got in the debugger: 
[image]

That's means this table is Read-only and not allow editing. But I never set this table in Read-only, it's really strange. This is code of this table.

```js
 public class Business
    {
        public Business()
        {
            LastReviewCreationDate = new DateTime();
        }

        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public string Id { get; set; } 

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("site")]
        public string SiteId { get; set; }

        public string UrlBusiness { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastReviewCreationDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual Site site { get;set;}
        public virtual BusinessUser businessUser{get;set;}

    }
```

Maybe anyone has ideas? And is it possible that reset `IsReadOnly` parameter to `false`?

Comment: IsReadOnly is a flag on the entry you can set. However, there must be something else wrong. are you sure your property on your context business is a DbSet<Business>? how is it configured (fluent API?)

Comment: I have ` public DbSet<Business> business { get; set; }` on my Context.

Comment: how is this dbset (e.g. the context) configured regarding this dbset? I know you can set readonly off on your entry(-set), however the standard behavior of the DbContext is not read-only data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fixed this issue by myself.
This is Exception that I catched:

```
Property: location, Error: The site field is required.
```

because I set the field's Required property to site,so everytime I want to update this table, even if value of site doesn't need to be changed, it always need to have been given a value by the client code.

```js
 public class Business
    {
        public Business()
        {
            LastReviewCreationDate = new DateTime();
        }

        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public string Id { get; set; } 

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("site")]
        public string SiteId { get; set; }

        public string UrlBusiness { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastReviewCreationDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual Site site { get;set;}
        public virtual BusinessUser businessUser{get;set;}

    }
```

So I fix this problem by simply adding `bu.site = siteE;` before`tpContext.SaveChanges();`

```js
      public void UpdateLastReviewCreationDate(string idBusiness, DateTime LastReviewCreationDate,string urlSite) {

            DAL.Business bu;
            try {
                using (DBContext tpContext = new DBContext())
                {
                    bu = tpContext.business.Find(idBusiness, urlSite);
                    DAL.Site siteE = bu.site;
                    if (bu != null)
                    {
                        bu.LastReviewCreationDate = LastReviewCreationDate;
                        bu.site = siteE;
                        tpContext.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
```

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

There is some sort of database validation happening preventing you from writing the data into it.
Actually you should see the errors if you drill into that array in Visual studio during debug. But you can also catch the exception and then write out the errors to some logging store or the console: